# Is the time series $Y_t = \frac{1}{2} Y_{t-1} + \frac{1}{2} Y_{t-2} - \frac{1}{3} \epsilon_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$ stationary?

Tags: time-series, stationarity

How can I tell if the series $Y_t = \frac{1}{2} Y_{t-1} + \frac{1}{2} Y_{t-2} - \frac{1}{3} \epsilon_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$ is stationary?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Cross Validated Stack Exchange! Could you show us what you have tried so far? Why would it (not) be stationary? What do you know about stationary series?

Comment: @Jan I know that I have an ARIMA(1,1,1). I mean  the p=q=d=1. I also know that a stationary time series is one that has mean, variance, autocorrelation, etc. are all constant over time. Now I need to connect these thoughts somehow

Comment: @Polym That is not what stationary is. Please have a look at [this](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/481/does-the-autocorrelation-function-completely-describe-a-stochastic-process/488#488) link.

Answer (score 2):

Letting $B$ represent the backshift operator, you can write this model in compact form as:

$$(1 - \tfrac{1}{2} B - \tfrac{1}{2} B^2) Y_t = (1 - \tfrac{1}{3} B) \epsilon_{t}.$$

The [auto-regressive characteristic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_model#Characteristic_polynomial) for the model can be factorised as:

$$\phi(B) = 1 - \tfrac{1}{2} B - \tfrac{1}{2} B^2 = (1 - \tfrac{1}{2}B)(1 - B).$$

From here it should be relatively simple to see if you have stationarity.  Do you know the required conditions for this?